# Reduce spacing between items in LOF and LOT

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm using **LOF** and **LOT** for my thesis(*book* class).

Both commands create extra spacing for items from different chapters:
[image]

**How can I reduce or eliminate that spacing?**

This is my code(MWE):

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithprefix{\figurename},
  dynnumwidth,
  indent=0pt,
  numsep=0.5em,
  beforeskip = 1pt,
]{tocline}{figure}
\newcommand\entrynumberwithprefix[2]{#1\enspace#2:\hfill}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithprefix{\tablename},
  dynnumwidth,
  indent = 0pt,
  numsep = 0.5em
]{tocline}{table}

\begin{document}

\bgroup
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\textbf{ÍNDICE DE FIGURAS}}
\def\bm{}
\listoffigures
\egroup

\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\textbf{ÍNDICE DE TABLAS}}
\listoftables

%%%
\chapter{CHAPTER 1}
%
\begin{figure}
 \caption{Caption of Figure 1}
\end{figure}

%%%
\chapter{CHAPTER 2}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Caption of Figure 2} 
\end{figure}
%
\begin{figure}
  \caption{Caption of Figure 3}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE

Comment: The \chapter command uses \addtocontents to place a blank line at the start of each chapter.  If tocbasic can't fix it, xpatch package can.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442470/space-between-elements-of-figures-and-tables-list?r=SearchResults&s=2|43.6003 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455059/remove-space-between-chapter-breaks-in-list-of-figures-and-list-of-tables?r=SearchResults&s=3|36.5684

Comment: Thank you @JohnKormylo! I used the suggestion of the first link and it worked! To be more specific, I added `\patchcmd{\@chapter}` for LOF and LOT in the preamble, previously I added the **etoolboox** package. Have a good day!

Comment: Yes, it solves my question!